# Codeigniter 4 session problem on production

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

I have problem with Codeigniter 4's session. Whenever there's no activity from the user's end for at least 10 minutes, Codeigniter will automatically kill the session and redirect my users to the login page.

How can I make it longer?

Upon checking on the `app/Config/App.php` it shows that the default is 7200 (s) or 2 hrs. I did not change this and it's working fine on development but on production, the user needs to login back if no activity within 10 minutes.

I tried to put on my `app.sessionExpiration = 7200` on my `.env` but still the same issue. I even change the session directory just to make sure it has enough privileges to read/write session to the disk.

Since changing `.env` won't work. I edited `app/Config/App.php` directly and put different value on `$sessionExpiration` but still the same issue.

Note: The browser was not even closed. Already cleared cache.

How would I make sure that my user won't be logged out automatically within 2 hrs regardless if there's activity or none?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, how do You check user logged in status!

Codeigniter4 regenerates `session_id` every `$sessionTimeToUpdate` seconds, `300` by default (5 minutes). Even if you have user activity!

This is can be changed in `Config/App.php` config file. You can increase this value, IF You really need that.

Using Codeigniter methods `->set()` and `->get()` for session manipulation will preserve session data between regenerated session_ids. 
Although, saving `session_id` in database, and then trying to retrieve and link previously saved data (as it was in my case) will not work, because session_id is changing every `$sessionTimeToUpdate` seconds.

```
$this->subscription = $subscriptionModel
        ->where('session_id', $this->session->session_id) // <<-- DON'T!
        ->first();
```

Try to change session handler to database, then You will be able to view and debug all  saved session data!